# iOS - How to find the right font size (in points) with the same height as a given CGRect?

Tags: ios, user-interface, fonts, size

Heading pretty much explains it. I have an image that I'm drawing text on. I want the text to be sized according to the size of the image and want to find a way to get a height for the font that is just a little shorter than the image itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, so for everyone who thinks an iteration is not avoidable:

```
NSString *string = @"The string to render";
CGRect rect = imageView.frame;

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithSize:12.0]; // find the height of a 12.0pt font
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:font];
float pointsPerPixel = 12.0 / size.height; // compute the ratio
// Alternatively:
// float pixelsPerPoint = size.height / 12.0;
float desiredFontSize = rect.size.height * pointsPerPixel;
// Alternatively:
// float desiredFontSize = rect.size.height / pixelsPerPoint;
```

`desiredFontSize` will contain the font size in points of which the height is exactly the same as the height of the specified rectangle. You may want to multiply it by, say, 0.8 to make the font a bit smaller than the rect's actual size to make it look good.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work reliably - I started a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663924/scaling-font-size-to-fit-vertically-in-uilabel).

Comment: @user524261 Good question, +1 for that.

Comment: Can I set size to 6.88 pt ?

Answer (score 1):

From here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Operations/Operations.html

```
CGFloat GetLineHeightForFont(CTFontRef iFont)
{
    CGFloat lineHeight = 0.0;

    check(iFont != NULL);

    // Get the ascent from the font, already scaled for the font's size
    lineHeight += CTFontGetAscent(iFont);

    // Get the descent from the font, already scaled for the font's size
    lineHeight += CTFontGetDescent(iFont);

    // Get the leading from the font, already scaled for the font's size
    lineHeight += CTFontGetLeading(iFont);

    return lineHeight;
}
```

To use this, guess a point size, find it's line height (you may or may not care about leading). Then use the ratio between the answer and the height you have to scale the point size.  I don't think you're guaranteed that the height will be exactly right -- if you care about it being exact, you have to iterate until it's close enough (use the new size as the new guess).

Comment: That doesn't answer his question. He's trying to get the right size for a font based on a specific height, not figure out how tall a font is. There's also a UIFont property called `lineHeight` that almost certainly has that exact same implementation.

Comment: Why not just UIFont objects and call `[font lineHeight]`?

Comment: @mbm30075  I wanted to show the components of it because the questioner might conceivably not care about leading or descent depending on what they are trying to do.  When I googled it, this is what I found.  Didn't see that UIFont also has it -- write a better answer :)

Comment: His answer doesn't avoid iteration. No matter what, you have to iterate to get the right answer.

Comment: You don't. Step 1: figure out the pixel-to-fintsize ratio by using an arbitrary-sized font and e. g. NSString's `-sizeWithFont:` method. Then multiply this ratio by the desired size to get the correct font size.

Comment: You only need to iterate if you care about it being very accurate for any font.  The ratio of actual to desired height is a really good guess, but you aren't guaranteed that this is right.  Typefaces may drawn differently at different sizes -- you are allowed to have different leading at different sizes -- there is no way to know that without getting the metrics for the exact size -- a ratio isn't guaranteed to be correct (but it will be close)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This makes the assumption that your font size will always be smaller than the point size of the CGRect. Adjust methods as necessary to correct for that assumption.

Try this. Works for any of the 3 main methods to create a font. Should be fairly self-explanatory, but increment is the amount you wish to decrement between checks. If you don't care about exact sizing, make that number larger for greater speed. If you do care, make it smaller for higher accuracy.

```
- (UIFont *)systemFontForRectHeight:(CGFloat)height 
                          increment:(CGFloat)increment {

    UIFont *retVal = nil;
    for (float i = height; i > 0; i = i - increment) {
        retVal = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:i];
        if ([retVal lineHeight] < height) break;
    }
    return retVal;
}
- (UIFont *)boldSystemFontForRectHeight:(CGFloat)height 
                              increment:(CGFloat)increment {

    UIFont *retVal = nil;
    for (float i = height; i > 0; i = i - increment) {
        retVal = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:i];
        if ([retVal lineHeight] < height) break;
    }
    return retVal;
}

- (UIFont *)fontNamed:(NSString *)name 
        forRectHeight:(CGFloat)height 
            increment:(CGFloat)increment {

    UIFont *retVal = nil;
    for (float i = height; i > 0; i = i - increment) {
        retVal = [UIFont fontWithName:name size:i];
        if ([retVal lineHeight] < height) break;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say that? It starts with a value known to be near the final, desired value (the height of the rectangle) and allows the user to specify desired accuracy to affect speed. How would you do it?

Comment: As the other answer does. Guess an initial size, then use a division + multiplication using the found ratio to calculate the given size. This is O(1), and gives an answer which is always correct, yours is innecessarily O(n) and it is likely that it won't give a correct answer if the desired font size is not an integer multiple of 1pt.

Comment: Did you see that `increment` is a CGFloat type? Kinda lets you go smaller than 1pt multiples. :-) Also, you're just assuming that the ratio gives you an exact answer, which is a faulty assumption. It gets you close, but doesn't guarantee an exact match. Plus, how do you guess the initial size?

Comment: I see that `increment` is a floating point value, but you can't just increment by arbitrarily small amounts. Also, guessing the initial size is easy: you have to supply ANY number (OK, maybe between, say, 0.00001 and 100000 for precision) as calculating the ratio will simply give you the right answer immediately.

Comment: Why do you think you can't increment using small values? Also, there are a BUNCH of values between 0.00001 and 100000!!! How do you pick?

Comment: Let's choose, say, 12.0pt as a reasonable first approximation. Then we find that it takes, say, 16 pixels on the screen. We want a font height of 24 pixels, so we calculate the corresponding font size: fs = 24.0 / 16.0 * 12.0 = 18.0. This works for ALL initial approxmiations, as the 'points to pixels' ratio is constant on a particular device.

Comment: Seriously?!?!? A down vote for actual code that actually works? What the $&@&$!?!!